# Burger menu Works on firefox but not on chromium-based browsers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, hamburger-menu

In my React app, I have a burger menu that runs as expected on Firefox, but it doesn't work the on Chrome, and I receive no console errors.

here the script that is responsible for handling the burger menu :

```
// Burger menus
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // open
    const burger = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger');
    const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-menu');

    if (burger.length && menu.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < burger.length; i++) {
            burger[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                    menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // close
    const close = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-close');
    const backdrop = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-backdrop');

    if (close.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
            close[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                    menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    if (backdrop.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < backdrop.length; i++) {
            backdrop[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                    menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and here's the code showing how its placed inside my react component :

```
        <nav className='lg:hidden flex items-center justify-between p-8 bg-gray-700 mb-3'>
          <Link className='inline-flex items-center h-8' to='/'>
            <img
              src='images/l.png'
              alt=''
            />
          </Link>
          <div className='w-full xl:w-auto px-2 xl:mr-12'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
              <div className='xl:hidden' />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className='navbar-burger p-2 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-300 focus:outline-none'>
            <svg
              width={20}
              height={12}
              viewBox='0 0 20 12'
              fill='none'
              xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            >
              <title>Mobile menu</title>
              <path
                d='...removed...' 
                fill='currentColor'
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </nav>
```

attaching a screen-shot of the expected behavior :

[image]

Comment: Can you create a minimal running code snippet? and not link to your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, try a simple logic and not a complex approach.

For example, when you click on the "navbar-burger" icon and then toggle the "open" class to its parent div "min-h-screen" and now you can control it from CSS.

Do this the simple approach after toggle the open class.

```
.min-h-screen.open .navbar-menu {
  display: block;
  /* You can also add css smooth transitions if you want */
}
```

This will work in any browser.